# Python CSV writer: writing uneven columns

Tags: python, csv

I want to write rows with uneven columns. Below is my code:

```
import csv
import json

path = 'E:/Thesis/thesis_get_data'
outputfile = open('maplight_113.csv', 'w', newline='')
outputwriter = csv.writer(outputfile)

with open (path + "/" + 'maplight data 113congress.json',"r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for bill in data['bills']:
        b = bill.get('measure')
        for organization in bill['organizations']:
            d = organization.get('name')
            f = organization.get('disposition')
            a = (organization.get('catcode'))

            outputwriter.writerow([b, d, a, f])
            outputfile.flush();
```

Every "bill.get('measure')" in my data, may have one or more sets of "d, f, a" from "bill['organizations']" associated with it. I would like that each set of "d, f, a" fill additional columns in the same "bill.get('measure')" row.

Comment: You can assign the list to a variable then user the metod `.append()` more data to the list if is required.

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
with open (path + "/" + 'maplight data 113congress.json',"r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for bill in data['bills']:
        b = bill.get('measure')
        tmp = [(x.get('name'), x.get('catcode'), x.get('disposition')) for x in bill['organizations']]
        outputwriter.writerow(chain((b), *tmp))
        outputfile.flush()
```

you need to:

```
from itertools import chain
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel,

I tried it and am getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Thesis/thesis_get_data/code for parsing maplight senate data part 2 .py", line 18, in <module>
    outputwriter.writerow(chain((b, x.get('name'), x.get('catcode'), x.get('disposition')) for x in bill['organizations']))
_csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: should be better now

Comment: still a little trouble:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Thesis\thesis_get_data\code for parsing maplight senate data part 2 .py", line 19, in <module>
    outputwriter.writerow(chain((b), *tmp))
_csv.Error: sequence expected